# How to install external launcher as a service with install4j

Tags: install4j

In install4j there is an option to install generated launchers as service, but I need to install a external executable to install as service. Install4j seems to give option to include external executable files but there doesn't seem to be option to install them as service. How can I do the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The external launchers in the launcher section cannot be used for that purpose.

In the "Service" property or the "Install a service" action, select "[Other server executable]" and then set the nested "Executable" and "Name" properties.